# Do I need to pack/unpack data read from a binary file before performing bitwise operations?

Tags: perl

I've read two bytes from a binary file into $data and now need to perform a bitwise and.

But when I do

```
if (($data & "\x100") != 0) {
```

I get the error Argument "@\0" isn't numeric in numeric ne (!=)

Am I supposed to convert $data first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using strings for binary operations?

Use `($data & 0x100) != 0` and, if necessary, convert `$data` to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have two literal bytes which should be interpreted as a 16-bit number, you need to unpack it.

On top of that, what ThiefMaster said.

Comment: Did not work how? Can you show us what you tried? `perl -le 'print unpack("H*","\x01\xFF")'` does what I expect.

Comment: I did my $flags = unpack 'H*', $data) but when I try to do the bitwise and, it says Argument "c280" isn't numeric in bitwise and (&)